# A term for adoption of a made up term

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for the acceptance of a made up term that then became the name of the object/idea/action once it was invented?

Example: Cyberspace. It was first used by William Gibson in his cyberpunk novels, but when actually invented, it now is widely used across the world (or at least across the United States).

Is there a term for this phenomenon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume OP is asking about the process of *becoming more widely used*, not the actual coining of new words/expressions/meanings.

The most common expressions I hear for this process are [**gaining currency**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/currency), and perhaps more informally, [**gaining traction**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/traction?show=0&t=1309890226).

There's also *gaining acceptance*, which I think is less commonly used. Personally I think this applies to a later stage in the process, when a neologism is subject to attacks from linguistic reactionaries seeking to preserve the "pure" language they grew up with.

Thanks to @Optimal Cynic for setting out the various stages in the process... 
*The original coinage is followed by awareness, currency, traction, acceptance, and finally ignorance (people forget or never knew it was once a neologism).*

Comment: How about **gaining acceptance**?

Comment: @Optimal Cynic: Okay I'll add that one too. But to my mind "acceptance" is a later part of the process - I always think of the neologism becoming relatively prevalent *first*, then battling it out with the die-hards who insist "That's not a word! It's not in *my* dictionary!".

Comment: That's a good point, I agree with that connotation. I'd extend it too - first comes awareness, then currency, then traction, then acceptance, then ignorance (after people forget it's a neologism).

Answer (score 3):

The term for the newly accepted word is [neologism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neologism).

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't think of what to search to find that term. I wonder if "warp drive" would also be a neologism as I know that once a "warp drive" (Aka Alcubierre drive) is invented, everyone is going to call it a warp drive, or warp speed, etc.

Comment: neologism refers to the new word, but there isn't really a word for it becoming accepted widely. Perhaps we should coin one...

Comment: @Optimal Cynic: That was what I understood OP to be asking for lol

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Me too :)

Comment: Even if this was accepted by the OP, the OP has explicitly stated that he's looking for a word for a neologism that specifically doesn't have a referent at the time of coinage, but eventually later does. If anything, to get that specific concept, one could say 'speculative neologism', or science fiction.

Comment: @Mitch: oic. I didn't read original Q carefully enough. Now I *have*, I think it's a bit pointless. What about ordinary words like **immortal**, **god**, **infinity**, and phrases such as **world peace**? They don't have real-world referents.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It could be that the existence of a referent was really not essential, but it happened to be the situation for 'cyberpunk'. I've noticed similar requests here for words with all sorts of conditions that end up not being needed (sometimes in my own requests?).

Comment: @Mitch: I think you meant *happened to be the situation for 'cyberspace'*. The word 'cyberpunk' was presumably coined to apply to a type of SF that *already* existed. And as for 'cyberspace' itself, it's really a pretty meaningless, somewhat dated buzz-word. People in Second Life or on Facebook, for example, are more likely to refer to their  **online** personae, not their lives in cyberspace. As do we here, I hope.

Comment: ...anyway, I really don't see much need for a term identifying the [hypothetical] process whereby a neologism is coined in advance of the referent being invented/created, following which that term happens to be the one actually used for the referent. The ill-fated **Concorde**, presumably, falls into that category.

Comment: @Fumble: oh yeah...duh. "cyberspace".

Comment: Is there a neologism for an remarkably extended discussion about a spectacularly fine distinction within an, anyway, utterly uninteresting question?!

Comment: @Joe Blow: the tempting answer is, of course, english.stackexchange.com